How to check if a property of a State object changed and update NavigationPath as soon as it does
I have a SwiftData model called workout that I Use as a State property in addWorkoutView:
 @State private var workout: Workout = Workout(id: UUID())

This model contains an array of another model called Exercise, I have a sheet that presents over this view and appends an exercise to this Workout and then Dimisses:
            let newExercise = Exercise(id: UUID(),exerciseName: selection!, date: Date.now)
            
            modelContext.insert(newExercise)
            
            //Unwrapping workout to also write to workout
            if let workout = workout {
               workout.exercises?.append(newExercise)
            }
            
            dismiss()

My question is how do I update the navigationPath so this new Exercise imidietly opens the EditExerciseView rather than having the user tap it in AddWorkoutView as was done before?
NavigationStack(path: $router.path) {
    VStack {
        List {
            Section(header: Text("Workout Details")) {
                TextField("Enter workout name",text: $workoutName)
                DatePicker("Start Time", selection: $workoutStartTime)
                DatePicker("End Time", selection: $workoutEndTime)
                
            }
            
            Section(header: Text("Exercises")) {
                if let exercises =  workout.exercises {
                    ForEach(exercises){ exercise in
                        NavigationLink(value: exercise) {
                            Text(exercise.exerciseName.name)
                                .padding(.top, 5)
                                .padding(.bottom, 5)
                        }
                    }
                    .onDelete(perform: delete)
                } else {
                    Text("No Exericses Yet")
                }
            }
            
            
            
            Section {
                Button {
                    showExercieSheet = true
                    
                } label: {
                    Text("Add Exercise")
                    
                }
            }
            
        }
        .navigationDestination(for: Exercise.self) { exercise in
            EditExeriseView(exercise: exercise, sets: exercise.sets ?? [])
                .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        }
        .listStyle(.insetGrouped)
        
    }
}

.toolbar {
    ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarLeading) {
        Button{
            showCancelAlert.toggle()
        }label: {
            Text("Cancel")
                .foregroundStyle(.red)
                .underline()
        }
        
    }
    ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
        Text(workoutName)
            .fontWeight(.semibold)
    }
    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
        Button {
            // Save the Content (Everything is optional so just save it as Is but i will demand a name)
            if(!workoutName.isEmpty) {
                workout.name = workoutName
                workout.startTime = workoutStartTime
                workout.endTime = workoutEndTime
                modelContext.insert(workout)
                dismiss()
            }
            
        } label: {
            Text("Save")
                .font(.headline)
                .underline()
                .foregroundStyle(!workoutName.isEmpty ? .blue : .gray)
                .fontWeight(.semibold)
        }
    }
}

.sheet(isPresented: $showExercieSheet) {
    AddExerciseView(workout: workout)
        .presentationDragIndicator(.visible)
    
}

Does SwiftUI offer a way to know when a new Exercise was added to the Exercise Array of Workout and instantly append it to the global NavigationPath?

So far I have tried this and it works to take the user to the new Exercise but It breaks navigation:   router.path.append(newExercise)
                dismiss()


When adding an exercise : add the workout to the model then put it in the navigation path so you do not break anything. The order of operations matters.

The workout only gets inserted when the user is done adding exercises to it, this way I store a temporary workout state object that I add exercises to then when the user is finished adding exercises and taps "done" I insert that temporary workout into the model
